# Altium - Defining top or bottom layers as a plane layer

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, pcb-layers

I have four layer PCB stack up but wish to use the bottom layer as a 'plane' layer instead of a signal layer. Is it possible to configure Altium like this through layer stackup manager?

- L1 Top - Signal
- L2 Mid - Plane
- L3 Mid - Signal
- L4 Bottom - Plane

I can use multiple polygons but for my design a negative `plane` definition with splits would be easier to work with.

Comment: I don't recal exactly how to do this, but I do know that most people (at least the ones I talk to) advised against the use of plane layers in altium. If my memory serves me right, plane layers do not properly do DRC.

Comment: @JorenVaes I've been using Altium since it was called Protel, and never had a problem with DRC on plane layers. I wouldn't be surprised if there is some particular situation that causes a problem on some particular version of Altium, but I don't think a blanket rule against using plane layers is justified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, when in PCB mode press d then k you can then edit the layers as such but you would change the lower layer to an internal plane

[image]

You don't specifically need to change the lower layer to an internal plane, a better way is to use fills or polygon planes for the lower layer and keep its definition as a signal layer. This is more appropriate to keep the power planes on one layer (and that way you can have multiple) whereas a internal plane can only have one net attached to it (although you can break these up with a 'negative' trace), much better to use planes.